# create user on multiple ubuntu servers

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

We have multiple development machines(each might have different applications,environment, but they are all Ubuntu 14.04).

Now once we have a new member, I have to create a account for him on every single machine, and ensure that authorized_keys are all the same.

Is there a way or mechanism to create account just once, and it can log into all the servers (using ssh key).

Comment: Have you thought of using a directory service like NIS or LDAP?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I just googled about it. While all the resources did not seem to clarify how is it deployed. And some of them said it's for mail services. Is there a central server (like a ssh db?) needed for this? And other servers configured as clients?

Comment: You can store the `passwd` database on those servers. ArchLinux has some [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_authentication) about this. See also [**freeIPA**](https://www.freeipa.org/) which integrates multiple technologies in an easy to use package. If I'm not mistaking, there's also the option of using a **Certificate Authority** for the user SSH keys. [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu) seems to have a tutorial about this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once with a simple design.

- Mounted the /home partition on the dev and test environments on the same Disk.
- This way the Users home directory is the same whether they are on Dev or Test servers.

Though the above idea worked, since we had a handful of servers and reasonably savvy users, I wouldn't recommend it.

Issues:

1) This is a seriously bad idea considering that when a user deletes something in his home directory on Dev, they wouldn't know that they are wiping it in Test too.

2) Access control becomes tricky since you cant control who can login to the higher environment.

So my go to approach has been to use script to move the account set up across environments/servers as needed.

```
tar cvf - /home/<username> | ssh <servername> " (cd /home/<username> ; tar xvf - ) "
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to manage is by using configuration management tools such puppet or chef which will help you automate the user creation, auth keys or any repetitive things and ease your job. Having said that, if you have no password login for root user on all servers then you can write a script which `ssh <host> "useradd [options] username"`.
https://puppetlabs.com